# Wrong breadcrumb rendered in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

**What I want**

is to have a *Breadcrumb* component rendered in the __layout.svelte and using a writable store *$breadcrumb* to read the data to display. The *$breadcrumb* data is filled in every route.svelte file with data provided by a loader

**The problem**

When the page is served (yarn dev) or rendered (yarn build *with adapter-static*) the breadcrumb has the data from another route and then gets updated when the page is rehydrated. Basically, it looks like the *Breadcrumb.svelte* component is rendered before the data is loaded in the view hence using the old store value from the previous page.

Rendering the *Breadcrumb* component from every single route fixes the issue but I would like to keep it in the __layout file.

Any idea on what to do ?

**The code**

*__layout.svelte*

```
<script>
import Breadcrumb from '../components/Breadcrumb.svelte'
</script>

<div class="wrap">
  <MainMenu />
  <div class="container">
    <Breadcrumb />
    <slot />
  </div>
...
```

*store.js*

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const breadcrumb = writable({});
```

*components/Breadcrumb.svelte*

```
<script>
import { breadcrumb } from '$lib/store';
</script>

{#if Object.keys($breadcrumb).length}
<ul class="breadcrumb noprn">
  <li><a href="/">Accueil</a></li>
  {#each Object.entries($breadcrumb) as [label, url] (label)}
  <li>
    {#if url}
    <a href={url}>{label}</a>
    {:else}
    <h1>{label}</h1>
    {/if}
  </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
{/if}
```

*routes/product/[id].svelte*

```
<script>
export let reference; // << the data comes in here
let product = reference.product;

import { breadcrumb } from '$lib/store';
$breadcrumb = {
  Catalogue: '/catalogue',
  [reference.category.name]: `/catalogue/${reference.category.slug}`,
  [reference.brand.name]: `/catalogue/brands/${reference.brand.id}`,
  [product.name]: null
}
</script>
...
```

Comment: I'm my case, the breadcrumb does not match the URL structure. I've used that technique before but it does not apply here.

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this?

Comment: I had not, but then I switched to the new sveltekit using adapter-node. Needles to say no more problems.